# How to make animation during Scrolling UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, core-animation

i have a question that is it possible to make animation on rotating a UILabel during Scrolling UITableView ? then how i can do it ? when user begin to scroll the UILabel will begin rotate based on scroll ! Objective-C and Swift are both ok for me

sorry for my bad english :)

> based on Fogmeister solution i wrote in swift and it works Well ;)

### #Swift 4

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      let maximumHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.width
      let currentHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x
      let maximumVerticalOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height;
      let currentVerticalOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
      let percentageVerticalOffset : CGFloat = currentVerticalOffset / maximumVerticalOffset;
      let percentageHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = currentHorizontalOffset / maximumHorizontalOffset;
      scrollMyView(scrollView, didScrollToPercentageOffset: CGPoint(x: percentageHorizontalOffset, y: percentageVerticalOffset))

    }

    func scrollMyView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView?, didScrollToPercentageOffset percentageOffset: CGPoint) {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
         self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (self.rotate(forOffsetPercentage: percentageOffset.y) * .pi) / 1)
       })
     }


    func rotate(forOffsetPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

      let min: CGFloat = 1.0
      let max: CGFloat = 360.0

      let value : CGFloat = (max - min) * percentage + min

    return value
}
```

[You can watch the animation Here !](https://yekupload.ir/09a6081d529cec1e/A281867C-AF5C-4FC2-B750-A8A761110D7B.MP4)

Comment: Yes it’s possible. But you didn’t show any effort or a problem to solve.

Comment: i'm new to coreAnimation and dont know how to do it @zombie

Comment: Don’t use animation to do this. Just use the scroll view delegate and set the rotation based on the offset. Because the scroll view is animating then just setting the rotation will make it look like it’s animating. http://www.oliverfoggin.com/controlling-animations-with-a-uiscrollview/

Comment: i couldnt  find a method for     [self scrollView:scrollView didScrollToPercentageOffset:CGPointMake(percentageHorizontalOffset, percentageVerticalOffset)];
 in swift , is there any idea? @Fogmeister

Comment: @mohamadrezakoohkan read the rest of the article. That method is one I wrote.

Comment: @Fogmeister please look at the code i just added , rotates the image at once 360 degrees and wont work anymore just once even if i scroll only 1 mm

Comment: Yes, that’s what the code you have written does.

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you it was great !!!! you rock \m/

Comment: @mohamadrezakoohkan hey can you please add demo how it shows???

Comment: @AmritTiwari i’ve just added the link to animation in the last of question , it works great

Comment: @Fogmeister do you have any idea on UICollectionView horizontal

Comment: @Fogmeister to animate every cell based on scroll or witch indexPath is user is

Comment: @mohamadrezakoohkan did not get demo? Can you please check it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find out the scrollview Y position, when you scroll. And if condition meets, then do your animation.